# To upload an Android App Bundle you must be enrolled in App Signing by Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, publish

I am trying to update the existing version of my app from my play store developer account. When I am uploading the **signed.aab** file its saying that:

*"To upload an Android App Bundle you must be enrolled in App Signing by Google Play."*

I have also uploaded the private_key.pepk file on the app signing page. But its saying that

*"The private key does not match the certificate we know for this app."*

I have already checked the key alias and passwords. They are same as they were used in the previous version.

Can any one help me with that?

for more info:

[Error While Uploading the .aab File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlHNK.png)

[Error After uploading the private key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzM6b.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
  does not match the certificate we know for this app
```

The meaning of this line is that the certificate is the thing where we add firstname, last name, organisation, organisation unit, city, state and country code. This information must match with the information in the previous certificate.